# Error Inflating class fragment in activity maps xml

Tags: java, android, xml, google-maps, android-fragments

This project used to be working before. When running the app, I keep getting InflateException.

```
04-01 12:16:36.102 14895-14895/com.example.ali.googleandroid E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.ali.googleandroid, PID: 14895
04-01 12:16:36.102 14895-14895/com.example.ali.googleandroid E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ali.googleandroid/com.example.ali.googleandroid.MapsActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment
04-01 12:16:36.102 14895-14895/com.example.ali.googleandroid E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
04-01 12:16:36.102 14895-14895/com.example.ali.googleandroid E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
04-01 12:16:36.102 14895-14895/com.example.ali.googleandroid E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
04-01 12:16:36.102 14895-14895/com.example.ali.googleandroid E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
04-01 12:16:36.102 14895-14895/com.example.ali.googleandroid E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-01 12:16:36.102 14895-14895/com.example.ali.googleandroid E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
04-01 12:16:36.102 14895-14895/com.example.ali.googleandroid E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
04-01 12:16:36.102 14895-14895/com.example.ali.googleandroid E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
04-01 12:16:36.102 14895-14895/com.example.ali.googleandroid E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
04-01 12:16:36.102 14895-14895/com.example.ali.googleandroid E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
04-01 12:16:36.102 14895-14895/com.example.ali.googleandroid E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment
```

**MapsActivity.java:**

```
package com.example.ali.googleandroid;

import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.UiSettings;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener, GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener, GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener {

    private static final int REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION = 0;

    private static int doubleTap =0;

    static GoogleMap mMap;
    MediaPlayer mp;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

    static Location myLocation;
    static LocationManager lm;

    LatLng latLng;
    SupportMapFragment mFragment;

    static ArrayList<Double> DataLon;
    static ArrayList<Double> DataLatit;
    static ArrayList<String> DataFirst_Name;
    static ArrayList<String> DataSurname;

    public static boolean closeDown = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.two_tone_nav);
        loadPermissions(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION);

        if (!isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()) {
            finish();
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        mFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mMap = mFragment.getMap();
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);


        buildGoogleApiClient();

        mGoogleApiClient.connect();

        lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    public void requestPermissions(@NonNull String[] permissions, int requestCode)
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for Activity#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }

        myLocation = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if (myLocation != null) {
            double latitude = myLocation.getLatitude();
            double longitude = myLocation.getLongitude();

            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(20));
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title(" You are here!"));

        }

        //insert gather data methods
        GatherDataLocLogon();
        GatherUserLogon();


        //*************Add for loop to load all submitted diary entries******************
        for (int i = 0; i < SignInScreen.DEntry.size(); i++) {
            String Lat = SignInScreen.Latit.get(i);
            double DoubleLat = Double.parseDouble(Lat);

            String Long = SignInScreen.Lon.get(i);
            double DoubleLong = Double.parseDouble(Long);

       //     mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);

            LatLng NewLatLng = new LatLng(DoubleLong, DoubleLat);
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(new LatLng(DoubleLong, DoubleLat))
                            .title(SignInScreen.ETitle.get(i).toString())
                            .snippet(SignInScreen.DEntry.get(i).toString())
            );

            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(NewLatLng));
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(8));
        }

    }
```

**activity_maps.xml:**

```
<AbsoluteLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#619ec9"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <fragment android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="362dp"
        android:layout_height="323dp" tools:context=".MapsActivity"
         />

    <ImageButton
        android:onClick="CreateDiaryEntry"
        android:layout_width="84dp"
        android:layout_height="84dp"
        android:id="@+id/DiaryEntry"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/trackownlocation"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/trackownlocation"
        android:src="@drawable/create_entry"
        android:background="@drawable/button_state4"

        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
        android:layout_x="267dp"
        android:layout_y="330dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:onClick="TrackOwnLocation"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:id="@+id/trackownlocation"
        android:src="@drawable/own_location"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_below="@+id/map"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
        android:background="@drawable/button_state2"

        android:layout_x="9dp"
        android:layout_y="429dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:id="@+id/help"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"

        android:src="@drawable/help"
        android:background="@drawable/button_state3"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/trackownlocation"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="41dp"
        android:layout_x="139dp"
        android:layout_y="431dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:src="@mipmap/settings_icon"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_below="@+id/map"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
        android:background="@drawable/button_state5"
        android:layout_x="8dp"
        android:layout_y="333dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:src="@mipmap/search_icon"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_below="@+id/map"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
        android:background="@drawable/button_state6"
        android:layout_x="138dp"
        android:layout_y="333dp" />

</AbsoluteLayout>
```

**Manifest file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.ali.googleandroid" >
    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
    -->
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.ali.googleandroid.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.ali.googleandroid.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

    <android:uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity android:name=".SignInScreen" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Entry_Dislplay" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Diary_Entry" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Recover_Code" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".SecDialog" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Create_A_New_Acc" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".ThirDialog" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Help_Guide" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".PersDialog" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MapsActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".LogoutDialog" >
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**build.gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.ali.googleandroid"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
}
```

Comment: can you post your manifest?

Comment: Absolute layout is deprecated long time ago. Why are you still using it?

Comment: Because I want to @VivekMishra

Answer (score 0):

You should use  fragment `class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"`... instead of `android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"`

Answer (score 0):

Add OnResume method and initialise and set Map there too

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your manifest:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
 android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Comment: can you also post `build.gradle`?